# How to make to the top of the page button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

I would like to know how to make a jquery button with the function scrooling to the top of the page. This button is usually found on the bottom of the page.

Preferably, is there a module for Drupal 6.0?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#scroll-to-top').click(function() {
    $('html, body').scrollTop(0);
});
```

If you want it to scroll up nicely, do this:

```
$('#scroll-to-top').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 300);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Haaaaaa! You beat me to it! I only pasted a link but still :)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you need to use javascript for this?  You can do it purely through html by setting an anchor at the top of the page:

```
<a name="top"></a>
```

and then wherever you want to provide a link to the top you can use a regular `a` tag with an href:

```
<a href="#top">Top!</a>
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to add an id to the html/body like..

```
<html id="top">
```

..and then add a link to it..

```
<a href="#top" id="top-button">Top</a>
```

While a lot of people do put it at the bottom, lately I've seen a lot of people put it fixed on the page, and and showing it when you scroll down a little, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tylermwashburn/ggbZH/).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Javascript. Add a `<a name="top"></a>` to the top of your page, and for the clickable link use `<a href="#top">Top</a>`.

You can achieve the same thing with jQuery and `scrollTop`, but you shouldn't.

You also probably don't need a "Top" button. Nobody uses them, and they don't add any useful functionality to your site. There is already a "top" button on the keyboard, "Home".